# Break point persisits in VS 2010 even after removing them

Tags: visual-studio-2010, breakpoints

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Possible to delete a breakpoint for good when debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581304/possible-to-delete-a-breakpoint-for-good-when-debugging)

Im using visual studio 2010. While debugging code, i put break point at certain lines. I removed some of them later. But next time when i run debug the same code, those break points reappers and i have to press F5 to skip them . Can anyone tell me why this breakpoint reappear even after disabling them . How can i prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had placed the breakpoints before I started debug. Then I removed them while debugging the code which was why its keeps on appearing again and again. Issue got resolved once I remove them after stopping debug.

Comment: No reply for two months.Resolved issue myself.